# custom fonts not working in my rails app?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use a custom font in my rails app, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've created a folder called fonts in the assets folder with the two fonts I'm using. And then I call the two fonts in my css file called home.css.scss.erb

CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Proxima Nova';    
src: url('<%= asset_path(/assets/fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf) %>', font);
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
font-family: 'Gotham';    
src: url('<%= asset_path(/assets/fonts/Gotham-Medium.ttf) %>', font);
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Then in my config folder in application.rb I've added

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"
```

But this still doesn't seem to be working.. any ideas why?

Comment: Does your developer tools console (Firebug/Chrome Dev Tools) show any errors with those fonts being loaded?

Comment: There are no errors in the "error" tab in Chrome's console

Comment: Try `src: font-url('Gotham-Medium.ttf')`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used custom fonts before but never need to use `asset_path` helper. Using relative path in CSS should be enough. My settings are similar to these:

```
# config/application.rb
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("assets", "fonts")

# CSS
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova';    
  // No need any embeded Ruby code here
  src: url('fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gotham';    
  src: url('fonts/Gotham-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: You do not need to use relative if you do not want to, but I agree asset_path is not needed. Just try `url("/assets/fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.otf")`

Comment: Relative path should the simplest and also applicable to assets in "vendor", "lib" once you configured them. Also I will avoid using '/assets/' in css/js path though I forget exactly why.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, however this still hasn't fixed the problem. I have copied exactly what you've posted. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try to locate the font once you are running (just throw the url in your browser) to make sure it is actually there.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4.2:

your_controller.scss

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Tungsten-Bold";
  src: url('Tungsten-Bold.otf') format("opentype");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

in config/initializers/assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/fonts"

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf .otf)
```

And put font files in >> app/assets/fonts/